# Hibernate Query Syntax exception : org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token ')'

Tags: java, hibernate

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxError: unexpected token: ) near line 1, column 56 [select concat(s1.student_FN,s1.student_MN,s1.student_LN) as student_name  FROM com.sms.domain.Student s1]
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:215)
```

Comment: It seems like you have an 'unexpected token' in your query. without seeing any code, that's about as far as I'm even going to try to go.

Comment: Add sample code for better answer

Comment: @jyothi What hibernate version, hibernate dialect, database do you use? Please also add the `com.sms.domain.Student` entity declaration.

Comment: hibernate 3 here is my com.sms.domain.Student {private int student_id;
private int family_id;
private String student_age;
private int notification_id;
private int gender_id;
private String student_FN;
private String student_LN;
private String student_MN;
private String student_roll_no;
private byte[] student_photo;
private String nationality;
private String caste;}